# Can't connect to Wifi with spoofed MAC address

Tags: android, ip-address, android-wifi, mac-address

I'm changing the MAC address on my Android device (I programmed an app); however, once I change it I get disconnected from the WiFi network that I'm connected to (which makes sense) but then I'm unable to reconnect to the WiFi with my spoofed MAC. I realized that I can connect to unsecure WiFi but not secure. I know the MAC address is changing properly because I did packet capturing with WireShark and the spoofed MAC shows as the MAC address on the packets captured. I want to know why this is happening i.e. what's the reason behind not being able to connect to secure WiFi with a fake MAC address?

Comment: Are you sure that the network you're trying to connect to does not have the mac filtering enabled?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I have tried to connect to several different networks and all of them do the same thing.

Comment: @Rachelle Where did you perform your tests of connecting to different networks... at school, at college, at office? Because at these places mac filtering is enabled more often than not.